# SoftInput.AdjustResize causes keyboard to flash when showing or hiding

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

We are having an issue in Android after setting `WindowSoftInputMode` to `Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize`. When the keyboard shows or hides, our splash screen flashes right above where the keyboard is animating. This is quite annoying and jarring.

Here is a clip of it, you can see the splash is peeking behind.

[image]

Comment: It will be good to provide some code, also to write what you want to achieve? Prevent the Layout to move, make the button visible... etc

Comment: "...our splash screen flashes right above where the keyboard is animating. **This is quite annoying and jarring.**"  - I don't want it to flash blue above the keyboard.

Comment: Oh it is hardly visible haha... Okey I think I know what is the issue, one more question are you adding the splash screen as android:windowBackground? and than as a MainLauncher has this LoginActivity?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You can see the answer, my guess

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see this might be the issue. 
If you set SplashScreen in Styles.xml something like this:

```
<style name="MainTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  </style>
```

And than just set the LoginActivity (login screen) as an MainLaucher the splashscreen is never disposed and it will live through your whole app. Imagine having bigger image on splash screen and drag it trough the whole app it will cause memory leaks after a while.

---

How to fix it. 
Create something like middleware activity which will be the same as the splash screen something like this

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MainTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Icon = "@drawable/appicon")]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        }

        // Launches the startup task
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
            startupWork.Start();
        }

        // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
        async void SimulateStartup()
        {
            await Task.Delay(500); // Simulate a bit of startup work. You can remove this 
            StartActivity(typeof(LoginActivity)); // Your Activity

        }
    }
}
```

Than just use a fresh LoginActivity

```
[Activity(Label = "LoginActivity")]
    public class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what we ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit late but this can be another solution for those who are familiar with this problem. I crated a splash screen from above code and set RequestFeature and Theme inside MainActivity OnCreate method. I also noticed that the issue can be resolved setting android:windowFullscreen to false. Here is my Code Snippet.

Create Spash Theme

```
<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="MainTheme.Base">
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
 <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>  
 <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>  
 <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>  
 </style>
```

Setting Theme on MainAvtivity

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
            base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);           
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App(path));
        }
```